# React 17: better-docs compatible?

Tags: reactjs, jsdoc

I tried to install better-docs but received the following error. Seems like the better-docs is not compatible with the react v.17? How do you guys work with JSDoc with React 17? Any advice helps, thank you.

[image: This picture is a photo when npm installed]

The below is the error report.
`.npm/eresolve-report.txt`

npm resolution error report

2021-11-22T05:56:23.456Z

While resolving: react-tsx@0.1.0
Found: react@17.0.2
node_modules/react
react@"^17.0.2" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"^16.0.0" from better-docs@2.3.2
node_modules/better-docs
better-docs@"*" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:

```
{
  "code": "ERESOLVE",
  "current": {
    "name": "react",
    "version": "17.0.2",
    "whileInstalling": {
      "name": "react-tsx",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "path": "/Users/Projects/salon/react-tsx"
    },
    "location": "node_modules/react",
    "isWorkspace": false,
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "prod",
        "name": "react",
        "spec": "^17.0.2",
        "from": {
          "location": "/Users/Projects/salon/react-tsx"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "currentEdge": {
 "type": "prod",
    "name": "react",
    "spec": "^17.0.2",
    "from": {
      "location": "/Users/Projects/salon/react-tsx"
    }
  },
  "edge": {
    "type": "peer",
    "name": "react",
    "spec": "^16.0.0",
    "error": "INVALID",
    "from": {
      "name": "better-docs",
      "version": "2.3.2",
      "whileInstalling": {
        "name": "react-tsx",
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "path": "/Users/Projects/salon/react-tsx"
      },
      "location": "node_modules/better-docs",
      "isWorkspace": false,
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "prod",
          "name": "better-docs",
          "spec": "*",
          "from": {
            "location": "/Users/Projects/salon/react-tsx"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "strictPeerDeps": false,
  "force": false
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "react-tsx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.5.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.1.1",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.54",
    "@mui/material": "^5.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.25.0",
    "jsdoc": "^3.6.7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "docs": "jsdoc -c jsdoc.conf.json"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real activity in the better-docs repo which indicates that the project is no longer maintained.